# Quickly generating large scale-free graphs with networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying to generate large scale-free graphs using the [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) package in Python 3.
These are my software versions:

```
python --version
Python 3.7.3

pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from /home/user/bin/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

pip show networkx
Name: networkx
Version: 2.3
Summary: Python package for creating and manipulating graphs and networks
```

More specifically, I need to generate scale-free graphs with vertex counts of 100K, 1M and 10M, respectively.
My code is very succinct:

```
n = 1000000 # 100K, then 1M, then 10M...
G = nx.scale_free_graph(n)

file_stamp = str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('.')[0].replace(' ', '_').replace(':', '-')
target_file_name = str(args.n) + "V_" + str(G.number_of_edges()) + "E_"  + file_stamp + ".tsv"
target_file_path = os.path.join(args.out_dir, target_file_name)

print("> Target edge file:\t\t{}".format(target_file_path))

with open(target_file_path, 'wb') as f:
    nx.write_edgelist(G, f, data = False)
```

For `n = 100000` (hundred thousand), execution took some seconds.
However, for `n = 1000000` (one million) or `n = 10000000` (ten million), the script has been running for some days now.
What I noticed is that memory usage has been very slowly growing.

I expect these graphs to take up more memory than what the processes are currently holding, which would hint at the generator logic being the culprit.
Due to the elapsed time, I started thinking the generation process is just slow.

I went to check the source of the [networkx.scale_free_graph](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/generators/directed.py) function:

```
@py_random_state(7)
def scale_free_graph(n, alpha=0.41, beta=0.54, gamma=0.05, delta_in=0.2,
                     delta_out=0, create_using=None, seed=None):
    """Returns a scale-free directed graph.
    Parameters
    ----------
    n : integer
        Number of nodes in graph
    alpha : float
        Probability for adding a new node connected to an existing node
        chosen randomly according to the in-degree distribution.
    beta : float
        Probability for adding an edge between two existing nodes.
        One existing node is chosen randomly according the in-degree
        distribution and the other chosen randomly according to the out-degree
        distribution.
    gamma : float
        Probability for adding a new node connected to an existing node
        chosen randomly according to the out-degree distribution.
    delta_in : float
        Bias for choosing nodes from in-degree distribution.
    delta_out : float
        Bias for choosing nodes from out-degree distribution.
    create_using : NetworkX graph constructor, optional
        The default is a MultiDiGraph 3-cycle.
        If a graph instance, use it without clearing first.
        If a graph constructor, call it to construct an empty graph.
    seed : integer, random_state, or None (default)
        Indicator of random number generation state.
        See :ref:`Randomness<randomness>`.
    Examples
    --------
    Create a scale-free graph on one hundred nodes::
    >>> G = nx.scale_free_graph(100)
    Notes
    -----
    The sum of `alpha`, `beta`, and `gamma` must be 1.
    References
    ----------
.. [1] B. Bollobás, C. Borgs, J. Chayes, and O. Riordan,
       Directed scale-free graphs,
       Proceedings of the fourteenth annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on
       Discrete Algorithms, 132--139, 2003. """


    def _choose_node(G, distribution, delta, psum):
        cumsum = 0.0
        # normalization
        r = seed.random()
        for n, d in distribution:
            cumsum += (d + delta) / psum
            if r < cumsum:
                break
        return n

    if create_using is None or not hasattr(create_using, '_adj'):
        # start with 3-cycle
        G = nx.empty_graph(3, create_using, default=nx.MultiDiGraph)
        G.add_edges_from([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)])
    else:
        G = create_using
    if not (G.is_directed() and G.is_multigraph()):
        raise nx.NetworkXError("MultiDiGraph required in create_using")

    if alpha <= 0:
        raise ValueError('alpha must be > 0.')
    if beta <= 0:
        raise ValueError('beta must be > 0.')
    if gamma <= 0:
        raise ValueError('gamma must be > 0.')

    if abs(alpha + beta + gamma - 1.0) >= 1e-9:
        raise ValueError('alpha+beta+gamma must equal 1.')

    number_of_edges = G.number_of_edges()
    while len(G) < n:
        psum_in = number_of_edges + delta_in * len(G)
        psum_out = number_of_edges + delta_out * len(G)
        r = seed.random()
        # random choice in alpha,beta,gamma ranges
        if r < alpha:
            # alpha
           # add new node v
            v = len(G)
            # choose w according to in-degree and delta_in
            w = _choose_node(G, G.in_degree(), delta_in, psum_in)
        elif r < alpha + beta:
            # beta
            # choose v according to out-degree and delta_out
            v = _choose_node(G, G.out_degree(), delta_out, psum_out)
            # choose w according to in-degree and delta_in
            w = _choose_node(G, G.in_degree(), delta_in, psum_in)
        else:
            # gamma
            # choose v according to out-degree and delta_out
            v = _choose_node(G, G.out_degree(), delta_out, psum_out)
            # add new node w
            w = len(G)
        G.add_edge(v, w)
        number_of_edges += 1
    return G
```

The main cycle of this code will iterate an amount of times equal to the number of vertices `n`.

Without going into further analysis, inside the main loop, `_choose_node` is called at least once and at most twice for each iteration.
Inside that function, another cycle exists, iterating over in/out degree (distributions).

I take it as `n` increases, so does the computational time inside `_choose_node`.

Is there faster implementation of this scale-free generator in networkx?
Or perhaps a function in another library (no language restrictions) which generates scale-free graphs with the same semantics as this one?

Answer (score 1):

There may be ways to do this that are more efficient; however, you're dealing with combinatorial growth--which is super-exponential.  https://medium.com/@TorBair/exponential-growth-isn-t-cool-combinatorial-growth-is-85a0b1fdb6a5

The challenge is calculating on (n) edges in this way grows MUCH faster than exponential. There are probably more efficient algorithms you could use but they won't win you much headway because you're dealing with a problem of raw math.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to decrease the time is to edit to generator code by

1. multiplying `r` by `psum` once (before the loop), instead of dividing `cumsum` by `psum` n times. That should save n times of unnecessary divisions.
2. Replacing `G.in_degree()` (outside the function call) with `G.in_degree(n)` (inside the function loop). This way, the loop

```
  for n, d in distribution:
```

Can be something like

```
  for n in G:
    d = G.in_degree(n)
```

This will save the hassle of calculating the distribution of *all* in_degrees / out_degrees of *all* nodes in the graph beforehand, hoping that the random selection of a node would stop sometime early enough to get a performance boost.

Comment: You may change distribution into a generator as well. But I have not checked that yet.